# Laravel Sail is not working properly in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-sail

Hi i tried to install fresh Laravel project using
**Laravel Sail**
docker environment. First it was showing me "Docker is not running" error. Then i found out, i needed to start docker as rootless. I solved it, reading this url: [https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/].

After that, I successfully installed Laravel using Laravel Sail. Then I ran

```
./vendor/bin/sail up -d
```

I was able to view Laravel project in my browser. But when i ran any other artisan commands such as `./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:list` or sail commands as `sail shell`, all the docker containers were forced closed automatically. It shows me this error.

> Sail is not running.
>
> You may Sail using the following commands: './sail up' or './sail up
> -d'

Any suggestions? I am getting this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version.

Comment: Run the command ./vendor/bin/sail up without the "-d" and show what appears.

Comment: How are you creating your containers? Are you using docker-compose? There's probably an error happening in your container(s) and they are not created. So since you have no containers running, `sail shell` also doesn't work.

Comment: @SantiagoCurvello I am able to view the laravel project in my browser. But when I run some commands for example ./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:list, all the containers, shut down automatically. I dont know why.

Comment: @MertMetin I am using 1st party package Laravel Sail (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) to setup my dev environment. When I run sail up, all my containers run properly. I can also view my laravel project from my browser. But when I run any other commands such as "sail shell" or "sail artisan route:list", then all of my running containers are shutdown one by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using Laradock before installing Laravel Sail. Maybe there were some conflicts. So I backed up all my databases, then I removed all containers using this code. `sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`. Then installed fresh Laravel project and it worked.

Please read my below comment as it is was a better solution for me.

Comment: Running these commands also fix this issue. 1. run `docker-compose down --volumes`
2. run `sail up --build`

Answer (score 11):

If you are on Windows and using WSL, make sure the WSL Integration is properly set:
Settings->Ressources->WSL Integration + Toggle Linux version

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to restart docker, then restart terminal too.

Answer (score 9):

very easy, maybe you don't have permission to run docker.
in Linux first use `sudo -s` and after user `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

Answer (score 1):

Sail first checks to see if any current `docker-compose` processes have a status of `Exit`. If any of them have, then it will forcefully bring down all other services. Which is what you were are seeing whenever you type any `sail` sub-command. You can see the code here: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/87c63c2956749f66e43467d4a730b917ef7428b7/bin/sail#L44-L49

Run `sail up` to start the processes and then use `docker-compose ps` to check all services are running and none have an `Exit` status.

I had the same issue and when reviewing the code and checking my services I noticed the database had exited soon after I brought them up.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people say this is due to a permission issue. However for me on OSX 12.6.2 (Monterey) it was because Docker is running as my local user and it wasn't in my path. Once I added `$HOME/.docker/bin` to my path it worked fine.

- `vi ~/.zshrc`
- add `$HOME/.docker/bin` to your path
- `source ~/.zshrc`
- restart docker desktop
- `./vendor/bin/sail up`

I'm running Docker v4.22 as a local user NOT the system.[image]